# Wrong item returned when detecting tap gesture in Jetpack Compose LazyColumn item

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

There's a screen in my app which shows a list of items, each of which has to respond to click and long-tap: when clicking, a details screen should open, when long-tapping a drop-down menu should appear.

With my current implementation (below), **after I scroll** to a random position in the list and click on one of the items, the details screen that opens is **not** the one for the correct item. If I click a *second time* on the same item, then the details *are* the correct ones.

If I dispense with the `detectTapGestures` modifier and instead opt for a simple `clickable`, the navigation works as expected.

I've tried using `combinedClickable`, but it doesn't give me the tap offset, which I need in order to properly position the drop-down menu next to the user's tap location.

Please help me understand what I'm doing wrong or how I can have the best of both worlds (i.e. proper navigation *and* drop-down with offset).

```kotlin
@Composable
fun PreviousThings(
    navController: NavController,
    viewModel: PreviousThingsViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {

    val thingsList by viewModel.previousThings.collectAsState()
    val listState = rememberLazyListState()
    val showScrollToTopButton by remember {
        derivedStateOf { listState.firstVisibleItemIndex > 0 }
    }
    val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.exitUntilCollapsedScrollBehavior()
    val snackBarHostState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    Scaffold(
        containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background,
        modifier = Modifier.nestedScroll(scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection),
        topBar = {
            MainAppBar()
        },
        snackbarHost = {
            SnackbarHost(hostState = snackBarHostState) {
                Snackbar(
                    snackbarData = it,
                    containerColor = Color.DarkGray,
                    contentColor = Color.White
                )
            }
        },
        content = { innerPadding ->
            val ld: LayoutDirection = LayoutDirection.Ltr
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(
                        start = innerPadding.calculateStartPadding(ld),
                        top = innerPadding.calculateTopPadding(),
                        end = innerPadding.calculateEndPadding(ld),
                        bottom = 0.dp
                    )
            ) {
                PreviousThingsList(
                    navController = navController,
                    thingsList = thingsList,
                    listState = listState,
                    getFavStatus = {
                        viewModel.getFavStatus(it)
                    },
                    favStatus = favStatus,
                    toggleFavStatus = {
                        viewModel.toggleFavourite(it)
                    }
                )
            }
        },
        floatingActionButton = {
            /*...*/
        },
        floatingActionButtonPosition = FabPosition.End
    )
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun PreviousThingsList(
    navController: NavController,
    thingsList: List<ThingAndImage>,
    listState: LazyListState,
    getFavStatus: (Thing) -> Unit,
    favStatus: Boolean,
    toggleFavStatus: (Thing) -> Unit
) {

    val dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM")
    val groupedThings =
        thingsList.groupBy { it.thing.date?.format(dateFormatter) ?: LocalDate.now().month }

    val currentHeaderState = remember { mutableStateOf<String?>(null) }

    LazyColumn(
        state = listState
    ) {
        groupedThings.forEach { (header, things) ->

            val headerStyle =
                header == currentHeaderState.value && listState.firstVisibleItemIndex > 0
            stickyHeader {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillParentMaxWidth()
                        .onGloballyPositioned {
                            if (it.positionInParent().y == 0.0F) {
                                currentHeaderState.value = header.toString()
                            }
                        },
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background,
                    shadowElevation = if (headerStyle) 5.dp else 0.dp
                ) {
                    Column {
                    Text(
                            text = header.toString().replaceFirstChar { it.uppercase() },
                            style = MaterialTheme.typography.labelLarge,
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .padding(8.dp)
                        )
                        if (!headerStyle) {
                            Divider(
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .padding(start = 8.dp)
                                    .padding(end = 16.dp),
                                thickness = 1.dp,
                                color = Color.Gray.copy(alpha = 0.1f)
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            items(things, key = { it.thing.id }) { thing ->
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .animateItemPlacement(
                            animationSpec = tween(
                                durationMillis = 400,
                                easing = LinearOutSlowInEasing
                            )
                        )
                ) {
                    ThingListItem(
                        thing = thing,
                        navController = navController,
                        getFavStatus = {
                            getFavStatus(it)
                        },
                        favStatus = favStatus,
                        toggleFavStatus = {
                            toggleFavStatus(it)
                        }
                    )
                    Divider(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
                        thickness = 1.dp,
                        color = Color.Gray.copy(alpha = 0.05f)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ThingListItem(
    thing: ThingAndImage,
    navController: NavController,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    showDate: Boolean = true,
    getFavStatus: (Thing) -> Unit,
    favStatus: Boolean,
    toggleFavStatus: (Thing) -> Unit
) {
    val dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d MMM")
    val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
    val screenHeight = configuration.screenHeightDp
    val screenWidth = configuration.screenWidthDp
    val ctx = LocalContext.current
    val density = LocalDensity.current
    var isContextMenuVisible by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var pressOffset by remember { mutableStateOf(DpOffset.Zero) }
    var itemHeight by remember { mutableStateOf(0.dp) }
    val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }

    ListItem(
        headlineContent = {
            AutoScaledText(
                text = thing.thing.title.dropLastWhile { !it.isLetter() },
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyLarge,
                modifier = modifier
                    .padding(end = 8.dp)
            )
        },
        leadingContent = {
            AsyncImage(
                model = thing.image?.thumb,
                contentDescription = "Image",
                fallback = painterResource(id = R.drawable.thing_image),
                placeholder = BlurHashPainter(
                    blurHash = thing.image?.blurHash,
                    width = screenWidth,
                    height = screenHeight
                ),
                contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(70.dp)
                    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(12.dp))
            )
        },
        overlineContent = {
            if (showDate) {
                thing.thing.date?.let {
                    Text(text = it.format(dateFormatter), color = Color.Gray, fontSize = 10.sp)
                }
            }
        },
        colors = ListItemDefaults.colors(
            containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
        ),
        modifier = modifier
            .onSizeChanged {
                itemHeight = with(density) { it.height.toDp() }
            }
            .indication(interactionSource, LocalIndication.current)
            .pointerInput(true) {
                detectTapGestures(
                    onPress = {
                        val press = PressInteraction.Press(it)
                        interactionSource.emit(press)
                        tryAwaitRelease()
                        interactionSource.emit(PressInteraction.Release(press))
                    },
                    onLongPress = {
                        pressOffset = DpOffset(it.x.toDp(), it.y.toDp())
                        getFavStatus(thing.thing)
                        isContextMenuVisible = true
                    },
                    onTap = {
                        navController.navigate("${ScreenRoutes.ThingDetails}/${thing.thing.id}")
                    }
                )
            }
    )
    // Drop-down menu
    DropdownMenu()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem recently. For me, what fixed it was passing the item, which for me was an integer, as the argument of `pointerInput`. I suppose LazyColumn is somehow reusing the items, and the pointerInput is not being recomposed unless we tell it to, by passing that key as argument.

So in your case, try doing:

```
.pointerInput(thing) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Why on earth is the API caching the callback and expects you to pass the caching key **by default**? It doesn't even provide a version without a key, for which is would update the callback every time. What happened to _premature optimization is the root of all evil_? I wonder how many people tripped on this one.

Comment: Can I pass onGloballyPositioned positionInParent forward to the pointerInput ?

Answer (score 1):

First this I would try is set a break point here:

```
onTap = {
    navController.navigate("${ScreenRoutes.ThingDetails}/${thing.thing.id}")
}
```

Then when you tap/click you will verify that the navigation library is working but see the id of what clickable is there. Is there a pattern to this when you repeat such as it always shows the first item details, the one above/below this item, or is it random?

A couple more things to verify how compose works:

- In the list item would it be helpful to remember thing or thing.thing.id? It looks correct as written but takes 2 seconds to try this.
- In your list item the parent defines a column. However if the drop-down compostable is not showing up properly below the main item then I would try adding another column there. The bugs you see are likely from two different reasons.

Comment: I've used `Log.d()` to see what's going on and the navigation seems to work as expected. Moreover, if I replace `onTap` with `clickable` it behaves exactly as I want it. Regarding your two suggestions, I'm not sure how to remember the id and where to remember it in - the ListItem? Also, do you mean to wrap the ListItem and the DropDownMenu in a column? Wouldn't a Box be better?

Comment: The Coloumn would be in ThingListItem so that ListItem and drop down don’t overlap which they would with a box or nothing. It depends what layout you want exactly.

Comment: If you use Log.d with onTap what happens? In the onTap method it must give the wrong id if the navigation is going to the wrong spot right?

Comment: In ThingListItem you can try val thingId by remember { thing.thing.id }

Comment: I actually *do* want them to overlap - the menu should appear next to where the user tapped, which will be on the ThingListItem. 
As for `Log.d()`, on first tap (after having scrolled the list) it shows the wrong id, on second tap - the correct on.
`val thingId by remember { thing.thing.id } ` returns an error, I replaced it with `val thingid = remember {}`.

Comment: Using `remember` doesn't seem to have any effect, I tried and I'm still being shown the wrong id's details.

Comment: Ok interesting. What id is shown? If you click on the first item and a couple middle items and the last item is there a pattern to how the wrong is is showing up? If thing.thing.id is wrong is thing.thing.date also wrong? Or if not are the ids not set up correct in the whole list of things to begin with?

Comment: As far as I can see, there is no pattern to picking the wrong id, it's just some random ID, but not the one that the item I'm clicking has.
Upon clicking, the Details screen invokes its ViewModel, which gets the passed id and then pulls the details for that particular id from the repository. So, date, text, etc. all correspond to the id being passed – it's just that this id is not the id I want. :(

Comment: Before the redirect happens though, in the onTap function, ${thing.thing.id} is being evaluated - do the id and the image and the date all match there?

Comment: Yes, the individual attributes match, but I expect that is normal, given that the whole `Thing` object has been passed to the `ThingListItem` composable.
Anyway, I noticed a pattern in the behaviour now: after scrolling, it is as if Jetpack hasn't "learned" that the scrolling has stopped and on the first tap, the tap doesn't register - judging by the lack of a ripple effect on the element; `onTap` is executed nevertheless, only with a different element's properties. A second tap, a second later, is registered with a ripple and the correct element/id.

Comment: Ok I’m not sure then. This seems like a bug with how onTap is working with compose and LazyColumn. The last thing I can think of trying is making sure you’re on the latest version of compose, or trying a more stable version if you’re on a beta

Comment: I was using some alpha version for Material3 and ComposeUI, but I changed back to ComposeBOM 2023.08.00 without any other versions. It's not that, the bug persists even with the latest stable version. :(